# Ruby on Rails: button_to uses absolute path, but I need relative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This is my first rails project and first rails post, so I might have trouble expressing myself.  I've looked around but couldn't find the answer to something I figured would be simple.

The problem is that I have a rails app that presents a button to the user, and the form action has a complete path starting with http://, even when the user is using SSL, so if they click the button they see a silly warning about the data being unencryped.  I want the form action URL to start with /...  Here's the code (HAML) that generates the button:

```
%li= button_to "Pay by Mail", mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment_url(@org, current_user.contact, current_application), :method => "get"
```

Unfortunately, I'm diving into a project and a language with which I am unfamiliar, I've also never seen HAML before.  I don't understand completely this resource: mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment, nor do I understand how rails generates the URL based on it.

Any info would be really helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment_path`

instead of

`mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment_url`

In short, the _url helper is absolute, _path is relative.  You can read about them [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls).  If you post the contents of *config/routes.rb* then I'll take a stab at explaining what that helper method is composed of.

Answer (score 1):

```
mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment_url(@org, current_user.contact, current_application)
```

is a Rails helper that generates a full url. If you would like a relative Url use 'path' unstead of 'url'

```
mail_in_payment_new_org_contact_student_application_app_fee_payment_path(@org, current_user.contact, current_application)
```

The details of what is going on is buried deep but it is based on your config/routes.rb file.